Can't access wordpress admin dashboard when blocking access to wp-admin and wp-login
I am having issues accessing the wordpress admin dashboard.
I created a custom login page and blocked access to wp-admin and wp-login. Everything seems to be working up until I try to open the admin dashboard from the top ribbon.
I can see I am logged in. I added the following debug code to the function that blocks wp_admin and wp_login. It checks if the current user is setup and is logged in.
function block_pages() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo "USER: " . $user->user_login . "<br>";
    echo "Logged in:" . is_user_logged_in();
    ...
}
add_action( 'init', 'block_pages' );

When I go to the homepage (mydomain.com), it shows
USER: <myuser>
Logged in:1

When I click the ribbon to go to the admin dashboard, the page redirects to homepage and it shows
USER: <blank>
Logged in:<blank>

I am hooking the block_pages() function to 'init'. However, it doesn't seem the wp_get_current_user() and is_user_logged_in() are available at that stage?
I tried hooking it to 'plugins_loaded' and 'wp_loaded' with the same results.
Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue? Thanks.

I believe I figured out what is the problem.
I thought the issue was with the block_pages() function. I eventually realized the issue was with my custom login page.
I use wp_signon() to authenticate the user. This function does not set the current user and the auth cookie.
I added the following code to my custom login function:
    ...
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        echo '<div class="error">' . $user->get_error_message() . '</div>';
    } else {
        wp_set_current_user( $user->ID ); //added line
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true ); //added line
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
    ...

It is now working as intended. Leaving the answer here in case someone has a similar issue.
